# How to specify AWK actions inside Nextflow pipeline?

Tags: nextflow

```
awk '($1<1)|| ($1>22) {print $2}' $input > $output
```

If i put this line into *Nextflow* (written in groovy(Java)) pipeline script, it will show an error that mentions problem with variable notation (these: $1, $2). It works fine outside *Nextflow*. How else could i put in the variables here for it to work?

I tried

```
 awk '(${1}<1)|| (${1}>22) {print ${2}}' $input > $output
```

Which outputs an empty file.
Desired output would be for it to just work in *Nextflow*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your process script section is enclosed in triple quotes, escape your literal $'s with a \ :

```
"""
awk '(\$1<1)|| (\$1>22) {print \$2}' $input > $output

"""
```

Wrapping with both your current methods cause nextflow to look for variables 1 and 2.

https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#string-interpolation

Comment: This didn't work, but i found an answer through documentation you linked and github: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/157

Comment: with `shell:` and using `!input> !output` ?